# SSH tunnel to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ssh, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

We're in the process of setting up Tableau connectivity to our company's sales database and so far, the people that have been attempting to connect (they're from some other company) keep getting denied.  The errors they're getting are as follows.

```
Unable to connect to the ODBC Data Source. Check that the necessary drivers are installed and that the connection properties are valid.

Can't connect to MySQL server on '[IP address] (61).'

Unable to connect to the server '[IP address].' Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.
```

Today we opened ports 3306 and 20560.  We were hoping we could set up some kind of port forwarding thing so that they connect to 20560.  I'm not sure what we need to do to set that up, however.  I was also told that SSH tunneling is an option, but connecting with PuTTY doesn't yield any results.

I'm at a complete loss as to what I need to do to allow them to connect.  I'm also not sure that opening port 3306 is safe and I'd like to know if I should have it closed.  I randomly picked port 20560 because it's not being used for anything.  We don't want just anyone to connect, but I've been told that the IP address connecting to our database may not be static.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more about your server infrastructure, database server / ssh server on the same machine? How you clients connect to database? using ssh to connect to server and connect to database?

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start because I know nothing about networking.  We have a business site and a phpMyAdmin/MySQL database that has all the information.  We generally just login by going to domain.com/phpmyadmin, then enter the admin credentials.  We have a database agent that connects to this database on certain pages, then grabs whatever information is required and processes it in PHP before displaying it.

Aside from that, I don't know how else to describe it.

Comment: have you setup a ssh account for them to access? or why dont you let them use phpMyAdmin to access?